# Nodemailer req.body is empty, why? Email is sending without error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, nodemailer

When testing the `sendtome` router, the email sends without error, however the `req.body` is coming in empty when `POST` to the route `/sendtome`. The email is sending to the email client, however its content is empty. Why is this empty, what is wrong here?

**postman**

```
POST: localhost:4444/sendtome

Body: raw

KEY | VALUE
{
    "subject": "test subject",
    "text": "test text"
}

Response:
{
    "status": "success"
}
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const port = 4444;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan("dev"));

app.use("/sendtome", require("./routes/sendToMe"));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on ${port}`)
});
```

**./router/sentToMe.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const sendToMeRouter = express.Router();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const transport = {  
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.PASSWORD
    }
};

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transport);
transporter.verify((error, success) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error)
    } else {
        console.log("Ready to send emails")
    }
});

sendToMeRouter.post("/", (req,res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const mail = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL,
        to: "sampleemail@gmail.com",
        subject: req.body.subject,
        text: req.body.text
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                status: "fail"
            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                status: "success"
            });
        }
    });
});

module.exports = sendToMeRouter;
```

Comment: _"req.body is coming in empty when POST to the route /sendtome"_  how exactly are you creating and sending this POST request?

Comment: @Phil I updated the post. I am using Postman to test.

Comment: `Body: x-www-form-urlencoded` and `app.use(bodyParser.json());`. See the problem?

Comment: send through body in `json` format

Comment: @Phil updated again. I got it. It was set to Text...changed to JSON and now works. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Phil that dropdown menu option was it, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

just exchange body with text

```js
let mailOptions = {
        to: 'sending email',
        subject:"whatever you want",
        text: `hello your order is confirm adress${lastcon.User_adress}`,
};
```